# React Native CLI - Bugsnag Error - Task :app:uploadBugsnagReleaseSourceMaps FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can somebody help me fix this error? Facing react native cli.

Execution failed for task ':app:uploadBugsnagReleaseSourceMaps'.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "app\node_modules\@bugsnag\source-maps\bin\cli": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Trying to build release APK. got this error.